# how to pass data/values from one class to another

Tags: java

I'm new to Java and I'm struggling to pass the variables/arrays from one class to another where the gui class should print the data from the logic class.

here's my code below:

`Gui` class:

```
package testClassesGUI;

public class Gui {

    public static void main(String []args){

        Logic logicObject = new Logic();
        logicObject.message(s);//here is an error

        Logic logicObject2 = new Logic();
        logicObject2.someArray(String[] someArray);//here is an error

        System.out.print(logicObject.message());//here is an error
        System.out.print(logicObject2.someArray());//here is an error

            Logic logicObject3 = new Logic();
        logicObject3.currentPoints((DominoPlayer[] player);

            System.out.print(p.getName() + " has " + p.getPoints() + " Points");

    }
}
```

`Logic` class:

```
package testClassesGUI;

public class Logic {

    String s = "hello";
    public String message(String s){

        return s;
    }

    String[] someArray = { "Great", "World" };

    public String[] message2(String[] someArray){

        return someArray;

    }

   //imagine i have imported this and I need to pass to the gui class
   public void currentPoints(CardPlayer[] player) {
    for (CardPlayer p : player) {
        p.getName();  //pass this to the gui class
                   p.getPoints();//pass this to the gui class
        }
    }
    //return p.getName() and p.getPoints()
}
```

Comment: Please stick to the Java naming conventions (Classes start with an UpperCase, everything else with a lowerCase), theyre not optional and improve the readability of your code a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normal getters don't take any arguments

Try this

```
String s = "hello";
public String message(){
    return s;
}

String[] someArray = { "Great", "World" };

public String[] message2(){
    return someArray;
}
```

Then this in your `main`

```
Logic logicObject = new Logic();
System.out.print(logicObject.message());

String[] array = logicObject.message2();
for (String s: array){
    System.out.print(s + " ");
}
```

Since `message2()` returns a `String[]`, you want to set it equal to something when calling it `String[] array = logicObject.message2();`

When you try and do this

```
System.out.print(logicObject2.someArray());
```

You get an error because no method `someArray()` exists. There is an array `someArray[]` so you could call it like this `logicObject.someArray`, without the `()`.

---

**List of all errors**

- `logicObject.message(s);` - There is no `s` declared that you can pass
- `logicObject2.someArray(String[] someArray);` - There is no `someArray()` method in your Logic class
- `System.out.print(logicObject.message());` - `message()` in your `Logic` class takes an argument.
- `System.out.print(logicObject2.someArray());` - There is no `someArray()` method in your `Logic` class.

**Edit: Conventional data `Accessor(get)` and `Mutator(set)` method**

```
public class Logic {
    private String s = "hello";
    private String[] someArray = { "Great", "World" };

    // getter method
    public String getS(){
        return s;
    }

    // getter method
    public String[] getSomeArray(){
        return someArray;
    }

    // setter method
    public void setS(String s){
        this.s = s;
    }

    // setter method
    public void setSomeArray(String[] someArray){
        this.someArray = someArray;
    }
}
```

Comment: fantastic, many thanks. I will now edit my question where i want to pass a void from logic with some arguments to the gui class. How do I do it?

Comment: See my edit... Also, you should ask a new question instead of changing your entire question in the same question already answered.

Comment: you are star, this is brilliant. Ok I'm going to post a new question. thanks again :)

Comment: here's my new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20567068/how-to-pass-data-to-gui-from-another-class-java

Comment: See my answer to that question

Answer (score 0):

You have undefined variable `s` in main

Instead of `s` in main you can write constant string `"I like stackoverflow"`

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "hello";
public String message(String s){

    return s;
}
```

This method is expecting you to pass a String into it then returning the same String.

Try:

```
public String message(){

    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write the following in your logic class class:

```
 public String message(String s){
this.s = s;
    return s;
}
```

I am not sure, but I think that is your problem. (If this doesnt work just swap the this.s and the s)