# How can I pass data from another class to a GUI?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

How do I pass data/values from one class to another using GUI? I'm trying to pass the message2 array to `namesOut` label in GUI. I'm stuck and getting an error.

Here's my code:

### GUI

```
package testClassesGUI;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;

public class UI extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UI frame = new UI();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public UI() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblDisplayOutNames = new JLabel("Display out names:");
        lblDisplayOutNames.setBounds(32, 25, 121, 16);
        contentPane.add(lblDisplayOutNames);

        JLabel namesOut = new JLabel(""); //here i need to bring the data
        namesOut.setBounds(32, 63, 228, 87);
        contentPane.add(namesOut);
    }
}
```

### Logic:

Here I'm getting an error.

```
package testClassesGUI;

public class Logic {

    private String[] someArray = { "Great", "World" };



    // getter method
    public String[] message2(){
        return someArray;
    }


    // setter method
    public void setSomeArray(String[] someArray){
        this.someArray = someArray;
    }

    UI logicObject = new UI();
    logicObject.namesOut.setText(message2); //here my error misplaced construct(s), variable declaratoridexpected
}
```

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: `setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);`  1) Don't set the size of top level containers.  Instead layout the content & call `pack()`. 2) There is no need to add the major tag in the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this in your UI constructor. You should create a `Logic` object in it

```
    public UI() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblDisplayOutNames = new JLabel("Display out names:");
        lblDisplayOutNames.setBounds(32, 25, 121, 16);
        contentPane.add(lblDisplayOutNames);

        JLabel namesOut = new JLabel(""); //here i need to bring the data
        namesOut.setBounds(32, 63, 228, 87);
        contentPane.add(namesOut);

        Logic logic = new Logic();           <<---
        String[] array = logic.message2();       |
                                                 |
        String s = "";                           |
        for (String str : array){                |
            s += str + " ";                      |
        }                                        |
                                                 |
        namesOut.setText(s);                <<----
    }
```

You can delete this from your `Logic` class

```
UI logicObject = new UI();
logicObject.namesOut.setText(message2);
```

Comment: so is it always best practise to bring everything into the GUI class rather then calling it and passing it from the logic class?

Comment: ok I get your point. But just out of curiosity. What would the logic class look like if I wanted to pass/call it from there rather then from the GUI class? I appreciate it.

Comment: You would still have to create an instance of Logic in your UI class. No way to get around it. You can't set text on a label in your gui from another class without creating an instance. In which case you could have a method that accepts a JLabel argument. But that is really poor design.

Comment: you might be interested in this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20595418/how-to-simulate-or-bring-console-with-scanner-input-into-jframe-application

Answer (score 0):

`namesOut` is a local variable declared in the constructor of UI. you cannot access it from `Logic`. declare it as a public member variable

```
public JLabel namesOut;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define a function. Maybe a constructor:

```
Logic () {
    logicObject.namesOut.setText(message2);
}
```

Also you can execute inside a code block, but it's not usual:

```
{
    logicObject.namesOut.setText(message2);
}
```

Comment: how do I call the Logic() it is not being picked up