# How to simulate or bring console with scanner input into jFrame application

Tags: java, swing

I would like to bring Console into to jFrame window application with ability to interact with the scanner inputs. Basically, whatever is happening in the console I would like to display it in the application window in the TextArea. Is there a simple solution to that?

here's my very simple code

ConsoleLogic class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class ConsoleLogic {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("How old are you?");

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int input = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("How many siblings do you have?");
        int input2 = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Thank you for your answer!");
        System.out.println("You are "+input+ " years old and you have "+input2+" 2siblings.");

    }

}
```

ConsoleGui class:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class ConsoleGui extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    ConsoleGui frame = new ConsoleGui();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public ConsoleGui() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblDisplayOutput = new JLabel("Display output:");
        lblDisplayOutput.setBounds(22, 25, 124, 16);
        contentPane.add(lblDisplayOutput);

        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();// ideally I would like to bring
                                                // console and the inputs inside
                                                // here
        textArea.setBounds(22, 65, 402, 185);
        contentPane.add(textArea);
    }
}
```

Many thanks for your help.

EDIT: I would like to have something like in this picture:(made in photoshop)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Unless you know how to write a Swing gui program, forget the frame and just use a [**`JOptionPane`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html), if all you want to do is put text into a textField. Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("How old are you?");

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int input = scanner.nextInt();

    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("How many siblings do you have?");
    int input2 = scanner.nextInt();

    String s1 = "Thank you for your answer!";
    String s2 = "You are "+input+ " years old and you have "+input2+" 2siblings.";

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, s1 + "\n" + s2);  // pop up dialog
}
```

**Edit:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String age = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "How old are you?");
    System.out.println(age);

    String siblings = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "How many siblings do you have?");
    System.out.println(siblings);

    String s1 = "Thank you for your answer!";
    String s2 = "You are "+age+ " years old and you have "+siblings+" 2siblings.";

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, s1 + "\n" + s2);  // pop up dialog
}
```

**Edit 2:**

I don't want to do it for you, becuase you won't learn that way. So here's a logic step by step of what I would do.

1. Have a `JTextArea` to show the conversation
2. Have a `JTextField` to get the input
3. Have an array of questions
4. Initialize the text area with the first question
5. Get the input from the text field and append that to the text area but save it to a variable first
6. Print the second from the array to the text area.
7. Get the next answer from the text field, save it to a variable and print to text area
8. Make up the final String and append it to the text area.

Note: Each time a the user hits enter in the text field, an index variable should be incremented, as to get the next index in the array of questions.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you answer. But instead of just getting the last MessageDialog text I need to perform the scanner input in the window. Basically everything what's happening in the console should happen in the window somewhere.

Comment: I edited my question. Is something like this doable?

Comment: How comfortable are you with Swing?

Comment: I should be fine as long as it is simple and straight forward. I even played around with WindowBuilder Pro a bit if that helps.

Comment: Do you know how you use actionlisteners?

Comment: Swing programs are event driven. They don't work like a console program that just keeps going till the program is finished. You have to program the Swing app to handle events. And event can be something like pressing enter after text is entered into a text field, or a button being pressed.

Comment: yes I know. I did some actiolisteners for button so when the button is pressed I would get a message or something but I was not able to do the scanner input or pressing enter :(

Comment: Look at my Edit2 and try it out. Come back when you get stuck and I'll try and help you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43215/discussion-between-medzi-and-peeskillet)