# System.readline() using textarea

Tags: java

What I have so far is something like this:

```
 JFrame jframe = new JFrame("Console");
 JTextArea text=new JTextArea(10,30);   
 JScrollPane jScrollPane = new JScrollPane(text);       
 jframe.add(jScrollPane);        
 jframe.setSize(500,300);      
 jframe.setVisible(true);
```

How can I use System.readline() using textarea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to simulate or bring console with scanner input into jFrame application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20595418/how-to-simulate-or-bring-console-with-scanner-input-into-jframe-application)

Comment: There are lots of posts on stackoverflow about making a console using Swing, which sounds like what you want. Google for "Console jTextArea" and other strings and you will find a lot of posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Truth is you cannot, however you can get the document of the JTextArea and then add a [DocumentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) to that:

```
JTextArea text=new JTextArea(10,30);
text.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
   @Override
   public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {
   // Handle text entry - just get the text when a newline character is found at the end of the text
   }
});
```

Basically what this does is it fires upon entry of any text in the JTextArea that you have created and thus you can check if the text that has been entered ends with a newline character, which will be the equivalent of the user inserting a command and hitting the Enter button. Then you can grab the text between this newline and the previous one (or the text you have in the text area, if it is only a single line so far) and use it the way you want.

Comment: Thank You! But what is the difference between addDocumentListener and addKeyListener?

Comment: @RickyCuarez DocumentListener checks for changes in the document of the textarea, whereas the KeyListener checks for key events. So the DocumentListener will check that the text was changed, regardless if you paste something in the textarea or add text manually, but KeyListener will listen for the keys (i.e. will get a keypress for something like Ctrl+V in there when pasting) and will also get key events fired even if the text area is non-editable for some reason. Therefore DocumentListener is preferred in this scenario.

Comment: So how can I collect the inputs until I press Enter?

Comment: @RickyCuarez you do not collect inputs until you press enter, but when you do, you can grab the document and split it based on newline character, then get the last line. So this will be when the DocumentListener is fired with input changed, get the Document, use String,split() with a newline character regex, then grab the last line from the array that is produced by that and voila, you have the last command given by the user.

Comment: Thank You Very Much for all of your answers it was all very helpful.